# What is the correct way to test an API with token api_key:access_token header?

Tags: rest, curl, http-headers

Following the below steps:

- created a new app at https://developers.kite.trade/apps
- obtained the `<API key>` from the app details page
- obtained the `<API secret>` from the app details page
- calling an API called [holdings API](https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v3/portfolio/#holdings) using curl like this:

`curl -X GET https://api.kite.trade/portfolio/holdings -H 'Authorization: token <API key>:<API secret>' -H 'X-Kite-Version: 3'`

All the steps look correct to me however I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "Incorrect `api_key` or `access_token`.",
  "data": null,
  "error_type": "TokenException"
}
```

I regenerated the `<API secret>` 3 times from the app details console.

Now, the question here is not about why I'm getting the error from https://api.kite.trade

The question is whether the authorization header is correct or not?
I have seen many APIs asking for [base64 encoded headers](https://www.base64encode.org/) so I did that too but the API seems not working.

Is it not the right approach for testing an API?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test your API request. Also, check what kind of authentication your API is using ( oAuth 2.0, etc). If that's the case, your request headers might look something like this:

```
{
    Authorization: 'Bearer <API token>'
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `Bearer` and `token` prefix?

Comment: I believe that will the depend on the type of API authentication, the 'Authorization' header parameters may vary. For instance, in oAuth 2.0, it expects 'Bearer'.